# Unable to added Facebook and Twitter to UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

Trying to share application on social median, and email, and message.
Since Email and message is working fine for me. 
But Facebook,and twitter is not all showing to `UIActivityViewController`

Below is code which i try.

```
NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                               UIActivityTypePostToTwitter];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[string, URL]
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;
[self presentViewController:activityViewController
                                   animated:YES
                                 completion:^{
                                 }];

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
         itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
        return NSLocalizedString(@"calling facebook", );
    } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
        return NSLocalizedString(@"calling twitter", );
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

@All
Please let me know what i need to do.

Comment: adding extra point when working on this.  How to show the user that facebook, twitter is not logged in setting. Its will help in user experience, if i show the alert message to end user about turn it on facebook, twitter to enable setting in order to post the application in respective social network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that just create one class for that like this.

```
SharingActivityProvider.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface SharingActivityProvider : UIActivityItemProvider
@end


**SharingActivityProvider.m**

#import "SharingActivityProvider.h"


@implementation SharingActivityProvider {

}

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {

    // Create the default sharing string
    NSString *shareString = @"";

    // customize the sharing string for facebook, twitter, weibo, and google+
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
        shareString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Attention Facebook:%@", shareString];
    } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
        shareString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Attention Twitter:%@", shareString];
    } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToWeibo]) {
        shareString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Attention Weibo:%@", shareString];
    }

    return shareString;
}

- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController {
    return @"";
}

@end
```

Then after just use below code, suppose button action.

```
-(IBAction)shareAppTapped:(id)sender{

    SharingActivityProvider *sharingActivityProvider = [[SharingActivityProvider alloc] init];

    NSArray *activityProviders = @[sharingActivityProvider,@"what ever text"];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityProviders applicationActivities:nil];

    // tell the activity view controller which activities should NOT appear
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];

    activityViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
   // [self.btnShareApp setBackgroundColor:OnebackgroundColorTable];
}
```

Comment: I tryed MVC approached, which is appreciated one.  but still its now showing the facebook,twitter in it.  I am using xcode 6.1.1 IOS Deployment target 8.1

Comment: In which divice you test this ? iPhone 6 ?

Comment: i am using Iphone 5c. [its an device]

Comment: in that device face book application installed ?

Comment: Its was not installed.  Thanks You.

Comment: @Thanks Dipen Chudasam

Comment: You always Welcome..:)

Comment: @ How to show the user that  facebook, twitter is not logged in setting.  Its will help in user experience, if i show the alert message to end user about turn it on facebook, twitter to enable setting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72051/discussion-between-kkmiw-and-dipen-chudasama).

Answer (score 0):

One mistake here is `exclude` `activities` also have `facebook` and `twitter`. Hence it will not show by any means.

**Note** `excludedActivityTypes` should be which you does not need in controller.

For example it should be:

```
NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                               UIActivityTypeMessage,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                               UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
```

Comment: Thanks, Even its not showing facebook and twitter icons in uiactivityviewcontroller.